# SharedPreferences returning null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've created a class to save some username and password using the Android `SharedPreferences`, its seems that the methods for set both username and password are ok.

But everytime i try to get these, from within another activity or by just trying to print out the value i receiver nothing (if trying to print the value) or null (if trying to get on i activity).

Here is my code:

```
public class AuthPreferences {

    private static final String KEY_USER = "userid";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "mypassword";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AuthPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("authoris", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        Log.v("MailApp", "User is " + user);
        editor.apply();
        if(editor.commit() == true) {
            System.out.println("The user was set!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The user was not set!");
        }
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, pass);
        Log.v("MailApp", "Password is " + pass);
        editor.apply();
        if(editor.commit() == true) {
            System.out.println("The password was set!");
            String mainUser = preferences.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, "456");
            System.out.println(mainUser);
        }else{
            System.out.println("The password was not set!");
        }
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_USER, "456");
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, "456");
    }
```

Here is how i'm trying to get it:

```
preferences = new AuthPreferences(getActivity());
    try {
        String mainUser = preferences.getUser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("App", "Could not get the user");
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you do not need to call `apply()`. Calling `commit()` is sufficient. I suspect the `editor` removes the values stored in them once you `apply()` and then you commit from the empty editor. Havent tried, I could be wrong. But doesn't hurt removing `apply()` and trying. And yes you might also want to use `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all because you use `Activity` as a context (you use result of `getActivity()` method as context). Since you got different activities you got different contexts so in result you  are accessing different shared preferences files (XMLs). In other words you are writing to file `A` in activity A, and then read in activity B using file `B` as your source. This obviously is not going to work. To have this all work as you expect you shall always use the same context for data that you want to be accessed across many activities, in this case I recommend to use Application context. Technically, instead of calling `getActivity()` to get context in your fragment, you call `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` to get your application context, so you will be accessing the same shared preferences storage file, not matter what activity or fragment is doing that write or read.

Aside from this there's no need to call `apply()` and `commit()` as these two is kinda equivalent and do the same. Please check docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

with

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Then replace `editor.apply();` with `editor.commit();`.

Comment: This solution does not work, i keep getting the null and i can't use  editor.apply(); on my if conditions since it's a void method.

Comment: Can you post how you use it in a normal activity please? I know how, but I need to check if you do it correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
editor.apply();
```

do this:

```
editor.commit();
```

Also you need to commit your edits by using the methods somewhere:

```
AuthPreferences preferences = new AuthPreferences(getActivity());
preferences.setUser("USER_NAME"); 
preferences.setPassword("PASSWORD_VALUE");
```

Comment: have you used setPassword() method somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i'm setting the user and the password before trying to get it.